# Cannot convert string to float in Calculate(function) + How to only take "1 returned value" from a function returning 2 values?

Tags: python, user-interface, return-value

1. I am having some problems solving the function Calculate, where I get the value from the inputs of GUI(xbar1, xbar2). The system always says it `could not convert string to float: ''`. Why?
2. The function "Calculate" is expected to return 2 values(if the quadratic formula does have 2 roots), but how can I just take only 1 value to insert to my GUI(x1Ans, x2Ans)?

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as TkFont
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
from PIL import ImageTk
import math
import numpy as np
import os


class CalQuadratic(tk.Frame):

    ShouldReset = True

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.grid()
        self.CreateWidgets()

    def CreateWidgets(self):

        f1 = TkFont.Font(size = 15, family = 'Courier New')
        
        self.xlbl = tk.Label(self, height = 1, width = 5, text = 'f(x):', font = f1)
        self.xbar1 = tk.Text(self, height = 1, width = 5, font = f1)
        self.xbar2 = tk.Text(self, height = 1, width = 5, font = f1)
        
        self.xsquarelbl = tk.Label(self, text = 'X2', height = 1, width = 5, font = f1)
        self.xnormallbl = tk.Label(self, text = 'X', height = 1, width = 5, font = f1)
        
        self.const = tk.Text(self, height = 1, width = 5, font = f1)
        self.Solve = tk.Button(self, text = 'SOLVE!', height = 1, width = 40, font = f1, command = self.Calculate) #BUTTON SOLVE
        #=================Showing Answer================================================
        self.Ans = tk.Label(self, height = 1, width = 3, text = 'Ans', font = f1)
        
        self.x1Anslbl = tk.Label(self, height = 1, width = 5, text = 'x1:', font = f1) #the label for the first ans (x1Ans)
        self.x1Ans = tk.Label(self, height = 1, width = 5, font = f1, text = self.Calculate)#this is the ans of x1
        
        self.x2Anslbl = tk.Label(self, height = 1, width = 5, text = 'x2:', font = f1) #the label for the second ans(x2Ans)
        self.x2Ans = tk.Label(self, height = 1, width = 5, font = f1, text = self.Calculate)#this is the ans of x2 
        
        self.PlotBtn = tk.Button(self, height = 1, width = 5, text = 'Plot!', font = f1, command = Plot())#BUTTON PLOT
        
        self.canvasMain = tk.Canvas(self, height = 600, width = 800)
        #======================Setting the Grid===============================================
        self.xlbl.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.xbar1.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.xsquarelbl.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.xbar2.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.xnormallbl.grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.const.grid(row = 1, column = 6, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.Solve.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 6, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.Ans.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.x1Anslbl.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.x1Ans.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.x2Anslbl.grid(row = 3, column = 4, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.x2Ans.grid(row = 3, column = 5, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.PlotBtn.grid(row = 3, column = 6, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
        self.canvasMain.grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 6, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW)
    
    def SetStr(self):
        if self.ShouldReset == True:
            self.x1bar.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            self.x2bar.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            self.x1Ans.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            self.x2Ans.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            self.x1bar.insert(content, tk.END)
            self.x2bar.insert(content, tk.END)
            
            self.ShouldReset = False
        else:
            self.x1bar.insert(content, tk.END)
    
    def Calculate(self):
        a = float(self.xbar1.get("1.0", tk.END)) #THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
        
        b = float(self.xbar2.get("1.0", tk.END))
        
        c = float(self.const.get("1.0", tk.END))
        
        
        x1Ans = str(((-b) - ((b**2) - (4 * a * c))**(1 / 2)) / (2 * a))
        x2Ans = str(((-b) + ((b**2) - (4 * a * c))**(1 / 2)) / (2 * a))
        
        self.ShouldReset = True 
        return x1Ans, x2Ans #strings
        
    def Plot(self, x1Ans, x2Ans):
        py.figure()
        
        a = self.xbar1.get("1.0", tk.END)
        a = float(a)
        b = self.xbar2.get("1.0", tk.END)
        b = float(b)
        c = self.const.get("1.0", tk.END)
        c = float(c)
        
        xplot = np.arange((x1Ans - x1Ans * 0.1) % 1, (x2Ans + x2Ans * 0.1) % 1, 1)
        y = a * x ** (2) + b * x + c 
        
        py.plot(x, y, color = 'g')
        py.title('My Quadratic Formula')
        py.axvline(x = 0, color = 'k')
        py.axhline(y = 0, color = 'k')
        py.savefig('SolveQuadraticFormula.png')
        py.show()
        
        self.ImageMain = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "SolveQuadraticFormula.png")
        self.canvasMain.create_image(400, 300, image = self.ImageMain, anchor = tk.CENTER)
        os.system("del SolveQuadraticFormula.png")
        
        
cal = CalQuadratic()
cal.master.title("My SolveQuadraticFormula")
cal.mainloop()
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SolveQuadraticFormula.py", line 112, in <module>
    cal = CalQuadratic()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SolveQuadraticFormula.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.CreateWidgets()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SolveQuadraticFormula.py", line 36, in CreateWidgets
    self.x1Ans = tk.Label(self, height = 1, width = 5, font = f1, text = self.Calculate())#################this is the ans of x1
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SolveQuadraticFormula.py", line 74, in Calculate
    a = float(self.xbar1.get("1.0", tk.END))


ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: if one says float("abc") what float should it convert to? I know of no way to not have a function that returns a tuple of two items not to return a tuple of two items except altering the function. However you can choose to ignore the second value.

Comment: I'm inputing both xbar1 and xbar2 with intergers, but it doesn't work, why? (still showing the same error)

Comment: According to the ValueError exception in error message the empty string '' is what is failing to convert to a float.

Comment: `command = Plot()` _immediately_ runs the `Plot` function well before the user has a chance to enter any data.